# does a date of birth have any specific meaning or importance?

Tags: pregnancy-birth

Does any one know if a date of birth has any meaning for us?

I would like to find out wheter the Torah or Talmud or any other Jewish writings has anything to say about this topic.

Comment: Are you asking about the significance of the recurring birthday, or the significance of the date of birth on later events in life (like in astrology)?

Comment: Another possibility is the fact that the birth date (and possibly time) is significant for bar or bat mitzvah as well as reaching the status specified for a particular age (such as 18 for chupah, 80 for gevuros, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Ben Ish Chai it is important. But even more important is one's bris day.
He writes in shana alef parshas Re'eh ois 17 that people are noheig to make their birthday into a yom tov, and it is a good siman, he adds that he too did it. He goes on to describe the bris-day minhag.

Comment: This question was marked duplicate. You might want to consider moving your answer to [the original](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7470/5323).

Comment: @Shokhet thanks for the heads up. Is there some special procedure or just answer again there?

Comment: Not sure. http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @Shokhet user6591 You can flag this post to ask a mod to merge this question into that one. If it's just one answer though then reposting is fine too IMO. Merging is more for when there is lots of material to move.

Comment: @Double AA ty. I already copied the text there though. Laziness won.