# Is a birthday cake celebration forbidden as a non-Jewish custom?

Tags: halacha, food, candle-lighting, parties-celebrations, hukot-hagoyim

From what I understand the custom to celebrate a birthday with a cake adorned with candles that makes a wish on and blows out stems from a [Greek ritual](http://hankeringforhistory.com/the-history-of-the-birthday-cake/). As such I would like to know if any halachic authorities have discussed whether or not this should still be considered a heathen custom and therefore prohibited.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7470

Comment: I believe there is a custom (possibly from kabbalah) not to blow a flame out with your breath.

Comment: @epicentre, one could use their breath but they can't blow out since that sound is the name of a malach,meaning if one sneezed or said shhhh to blow it out their shouldn't be an issue (saw it in a Shu"t)

Comment: @Epicentre I've only ever heard that with regard to the havdalah candle. Sounds like a rather burdensome custom otherwise...

Comment: http://rchaimqoton.blogspot.co.il/2007/04/happy-birthday.html

Comment: @Loewian I've heard it even re matches used to light shabbat/chanukah/havdalah candles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Halachically Speaking - page 11](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Vol9Issue11.pdf) quoting Miyum Hahalacha 4:46 says one should not put candles on the birthday cake.

> The practice of putting candles on a birthday cake corresponding to
>   the celebrant’s age does not stem from a Jewish custom and should not
>   be done

[Rabbi Eli Mansour](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=1210) quoting Rabbi Avraham Blumenkrantz says it should not be done.

> It should also be mentioned that Rabbi Avraham Blumenkrantz, in one of
>   his Pesach digests, documents that the entire concept of "birthday
>   candles" has its origins in ancient pagan customs, and therefore it
>   should be avoided altogether

Answer (score 0):

The Dayanim of Dinonline [say](https://dinonline.org/2017/10/01/blowing-out-candles-on-a-birthday-cake/)

> In Greek times, people on their birthday
> would try to find favor in the eyes of the moon goddess, Artemis. In
> an attempt to do so, they would make round cakes (to symbolize the
> full moon) and light candles on top (to symbolize the light of the
> moon.) They would then ask the moon goddess to grant their requests.
> Therefore blowing out the candles and even lighting them should not be
> done.